# Why cookies work in localhost and not in Vercel deployed MERN project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, mern

Why does my project MERN work perfectly in localhost and not in Vercel?

**Login controllers** :

```
 login: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { email, password } = req.body

            const user = await Users.findOne({email})
            .populate("followers following", "avatar username fullname followers following")

            if(!user) return res.status(400).json({msg: "Cette Email n'existe pas."})

            const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
            if(!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({msg: "Mot de passe incorrecte."})

            const access_token = createAccessToken({id: user._id})
            const refresh_token = createRefreshToken({id: user._id})

            res.cookie('refreshtoken', refresh_token, {
                httpOnly: true,
                path: '/api/refresh_token',
                maxAge: 30*24*60*60*1000 // 30days
            })

            res.json({
                msg: 'Connexion terminée!',
                access_token,
                user: {
                    ...user._doc,
                    password: ''
                }
            })
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
        }
    },
```

It is creating cookie perfectly but does not appear in
**Inspection => Application => Cookies**
And when I refresh, the following code does not work:

```
generateAccessToken: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const rf_token = req.cookies.refreshtoken
            if(!rf_token) return res.status(400).json({msg: "Connectez-vous SVP."})

            jwt.verify(rf_token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, async(err, result) => {
                if(err) return res.status(400).json({msg: "Connectez-vous SVP."})

                const user = await Users.findById(result.id).select("-password")
                .populate('followers following', 'avatar username fullname followers following')

                if(!user) return res.status(400).json({msg: "Utilisateur n'existe pas."})

                const access_token = createAccessToken({id: result.id})

                res.json({
                    access_token,
                    user
                })
            })
            
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
        }
    }
```

Why does the tf_token is empty? And works in localhost works but not in Vercel?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `/api/refresh_token` path is valid on localhost. However, when you deploy the application to a different domain, the `/api/refresh_token` path may not be valid, and the cookie will not be sent or recognized for other routes on the new domain.

To fix this, set the path to `/`, which will make the cookie valid for all routes on the domain

```js
res.cookie("refreshtoken", refresh_token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  path: "/",
  maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30days
});
```

Comment: Thank's for the answers, i did that but already the same error cookie undiffined

Answer (score 0):

Your code everything is ok, and you have to change path from `/api/refresh_token` to `/`

To fix this, set the path to `/`, which will make the cookie valid for all routes on the domain

```js
res.cookie("refreshtoken", refresh_token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  path: "/",
  maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30days
});
```

And also I think your `browser's third-party cookie is disabled`; that's why you are not getting cookies. You have to enable your third-party cookie in your browser if it is disabled.
I faced this same issue. After enabling it, the code had been working perfectly.

You just enable it.

[image]